# Custom normalizer throws error once enabled

Tags: 8

I wrote a custom normalizer last year to alter link output (using https://www.mediacurrent.com/blog/using-normalizers-alter-rest-json-structure-drupal-8/ as reference) for use with JSON:API output, which worked like a charm. However, at the moment I get a big error (see below) when I've enabled the module.

The error:

```
TypeError: Adaptor Drupal\jsonapi_extras\Plugin\ResourceFieldEnhancerBase returned invalid output data: [] in Drupal\jsonapi_extras\Plugin\ResourceFieldEnhancerBase->undoTransform() (line 66 of /vendor/e0ipso/shaper/src/DataAdaptor/DataAdaptorTransformerTrait.php).
Drupal\jsonapi_extras\Plugin\ResourceFieldEnhancerBase->undoTransform(Array, Object) (Line: 65)
Drupal\jsonapi_extras\Normalizer\ResourceIdentifierNormalizer->normalize(Object, 'api_json', Array) (Line: 143)
Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer->normalize(Object, 'api_json', Array) (Line: 62)
Drupal\jsonapi\Serializer\Serializer->normalize(Object, 'api_json', Array) (Line: 26)
Drupal\jsonapi\Normalizer\DataNormalizer->Drupal\jsonapi\Normalizer\{closure}(Object)
array_map(Object, Array) (Line: 27)
Drupal\jsonapi\Normalizer\DataNormalizer->normalize(Object, 'api_json', Array) (Line: 143)
Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer->normalize(Object, 'api_json', Array) (Line: 62)
Drupal\jsonapi\Serializer\Serializer->normalize(Object, 'api_json', Array) (Line: 26)
Drupal\jsonapi\Normalizer\RelationshipNormalizer->normalize(Object, 'api_json', Array) (Line: 143)
Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer->normalize(Object, 'api_json', Array) (Line: 62)
Drupal\jsonapi\Serializer\Serializer->normalize(Object, 'api_json', Array) (Line: 187)
Drupal\jsonapi\Normalizer\ResourceObjectNormalizer->serializeField(Object, Array, 'api_json') (Line: 121)
Drupal\jsonapi\Normalizer\ResourceObjectNormalizer->getNormalization(Array, Object, 'api_json', Array) (Line: 73)
Drupal\jsonapi\Normalizer\ResourceObjectNormalizer->normalize(Object, 'api_json', Array) (Line: 38)
Drupal\jsonapi_extras\Normalizer\JsonApiNormalizerDecoratorBase->normalize(Object, 'api_json', Array) (Line: 24)
Drupal\jsonapi_extras\Normalizer\ResourceObjectNormalizer->normalize(Object, 'api_json', Array) (Line: 143)
Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer->normalize(Object, 'api_json', Array) (Line: 62)
Drupal\jsonapi\Serializer\Serializer->normalize(Object, 'api_json', Array) (Line: 26)
Drupal\jsonapi\Normalizer\DataNormalizer->Drupal\jsonapi\Normalizer\{closure}(Object)
array_map(Object, Array) (Line: 27)
Drupal\jsonapi\Normalizer\DataNormalizer->normalize(Object, 'api_json', Array) (Line: 143)
Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer->normalize(Object, 'api_json', Array) (Line: 62)
Drupal\jsonapi\Serializer\Serializer->normalize(Object, 'api_json', Array) (Line: 193)
Drupal\jsonapi\Normalizer\JsonApiDocumentTopLevelNormalizer->normalize(Object, 'api_json', Array) (Line: 143)
Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer->normalize(Object, 'api_json', Array) (Line: 62)
Drupal\jsonapi\Serializer\Serializer->normalize(Object, 'api_json', Array) (Line: 120)
Drupal\jsonapi\EventSubscriber\ResourceResponseSubscriber->renderResponseBody(Object, Object, Object, 'api_json') (Line: 85)
Drupal\jsonapi\EventSubscriber\ResourceResponseSubscriber->onResponse(Object, 'kernel.response', Object)
call_user_func(Array, Object, 'kernel.response', Object) (Line: 111)
Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.response', Object) (Line: 191)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->filterResponse(Object, Object, 1) (Line: 173)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object, 1) (Line: 68)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 57)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 191)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->fetch(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 128)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->lookup(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 82)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 52)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 23)
Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 708)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)
```

My services.yml

```
services:
  custom_normalizer.typed_data:
    class: Drupal\custom_normalizer\Normalizer\LinkNormalizer
    tags:
      - { name: normalizer, priority: 10 }
```

The LinkNormalizer file:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\custom_normalizer\Normalizer;

use Drupal\Core\Url;
use Drupal\link\Plugin\Field\FieldType\LinkItem;
use Drupal\serialization\Normalizer\NormalizerBase;

/**
 * Converts typed data objects to arrays.
 */
class LinkNormalizer extends NormalizerBase
{
    /**
     * The interface or class that this Normalizer supports.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $supportedInterfaceOrClass = 'Drupal\Core\TypedData\TypedDataInterface';

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function normalize($object, $format = null, array $context = array())
    {
        $value = $object->getValue();
        $parent = $object->getParent();
        if ($parent instanceof LinkItem) {
            $internalLink = $parent->get('uri')->getValue();
            $link = Url::fromUri($internalLink, array('absolute' => false))->toString();
            $object->getParent()->get('options')->setValue(['url' => $link]);
        }
        return $value;
    }
}
```

If anyone has an idea what I'm doing wrong (or what has changed), that would be great. I haven't found anything useful yet.

Stephan

Comment: What is being returned? What is it expecting? The error is "Adaptor Drupal\jsonapi_extras\Plugin\ResourceFieldEnhancerBase returned invalid output data: []"

Comment: It actually doesn't matter what I return, albeit a string, an array, an object, null, it always throws the same error.

Comment: Your class isn't mentioned in the trace which could suggest it's not that code causing the problem. What else does the module do? If you disable the module does the error literally disappear and then reappear as soon as the module is enabled again? Is the error on every page or just happening when you consume a related rest resource?

Comment: The module only contains the code given above. The error is only shown when I consume a jsonapi resource, and disappears when I disable the module.

Answer (score 0):

Your normalizer is basically a null function:

```
$value = $object->getValue();
```

You return typed data values without applying any changes.

You are only doing this to get hold of a different object, the parent field. This is not what the method is supposed to do according to the interface. The result is unpredictable. Instead try to target the normalization process of the field or entity directly.

Comment: Unfortunately, just enabling the module (even with an empty `normalize` function throws the error

Comment: I don't know what you mean by empty, but my advice was to normalize a field or entity directly where you normalize according to the interface.